# What are open-loop and closed-loop modes of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I came across the following line in the book ‘Deep Learning (Ian Goodfellow) 10.2.1, pg 374;

> The disadvantage of strict teacher forcing arises if the network is going to be later used in an **open-loop** mode, with the network outputs fed back as input.

Please explain the difference between these modes.